# Selenium IDE cannot detect drop down selection, how to resolve this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, selenium-ide

I recorded one interaction that expands a drop-down menu and selects the 3rd option in Selenium IDE. Now when I replay it, I see the drop-down gets expanded but the option does not get selected. Can anyone please help me solve this problem?

I'm providing screenshots of the pages source/html code here:
[Red arrows show the corresponding html tags]

[image]

Here is the recorded script:
[Red error shows the corresponding selenium script command]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code for driving Selenium? It seems likely the problem is there.

Comment: Here a Google document (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dfdkwZA-jsU06gKoralXGCv_8uqE1JXEn2spP_GYZ4w/edit?usp=sharing) with the source code, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to the problem and it's working. Please let me know if you have any better/easy solution than this.

We needed to use X-path to detect the drop-down. I used Chrome's developer tool to capture the x-path : selected the drop-down item > right-clicked > Copy > X-path. Providing a screenshot below:

[image]